# Are my verb tenses correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, verbs, tenses

“Never have I imagined that the day will come when my dad and I have a coherent conversation on electricity related topics.”

Comment: There is nothing wrong with those tenses. (It may be a fact. *I have never imagined X*.) But what are you trying to express?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it should be:

> "Never would I have imagined that the day would come when my dad and I would have a coherent conversation on electricity-related topics."

Comment: Another answer without argument or justification. Please read the Help on answering questions.

Comment: [It says](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), "Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful [but] fuller explanations are better."  [Also it says](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), "Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final statement indicating that the question has now been answered perfectly. It simply means that the author received an answer that worked for them personally." In my view, some people prefer fast answers than thorough answers. You are welcome to provide a longer answer if you have the time.

Comment: “Feel free to add your own answer” doesn’t answer my question of how the poster can tell if you are right or not. I am trying to help you with the same criticism that I received when I started on this site. Further, I don’t think that the questions you are answering are not at the level of this site (see Tour) and rather than answer I would vote to close as more suitable for ELL.

Comment: A significant proportion of the questions here would be more suitable for ELL, but I don't have sufficient reputation to vote to close answers. Perhaps there just aren't enough people on this site for that to work. This question has only been viewed 15 times in the last 8 hours. I'm trying to build rep by giving short answers quickly.

Comment: You have no idea how long the close vote queue is. This site has a lot of users who can and do give close votes, but not enough to deal with all the people that ignore the statement that the site is for “linguists, etymologists and serious language enthusiasts”.  As for building up a reputation, I would think about the real meaning of that word.